# Hibernate @Formula returns an old value in PUT response

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

My Spring boot app has 2 Entities - Document and Card. Card has column dtFrom. Clients have to work with column daysOnDtConfirm (Document.dtConfirm - dtFrom). Annotation @Formula for GET requests works great, but in PUT response returns an old value of daysOnDtConfirm. How return a new value?

```
@Entity
@Table(name="document")
public class Document extends BaseEntity{
  private String name; 

  @Column(name = "dt_confirm")       
  @Type(type="org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentLocalDateTime")
  @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME)
  @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING)
  private LocalDateTime dtConfirm ;

  @Column(name = "contragent_name")
  private String contragentName;
     ....
  //CARD
  @OneToMany(mappedBy="document" , fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  private List<Card> cards = new ArrayList<Card>();

  public  List<Card> getCards() {
    if (this.cards == null) {
        this.cards = new ArrayList<Card>();
    }
    return this.cards;
   }

 public void setCard(Card card) {
      getCards().add(card);
      card.setDocument(this);
  }

 public int getNrOfCards() {
    return getCards().size();
  }
 ....
}
```

And

```
@Entity
@Table(name="card")
public class Card extends BaseEntity {
  @ManyToOne
  @JsonIgnore
  @JoinColumn(name = "document_id")
  private Document document;

  private String name;

  private double quantity;

  @Column(name = "dt_from")
  @Type(type="org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentLocalDate")
  @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME)
  @JsonIgnore
  private LocalDate dtFrom ;

  @Formula("(select IFNULL(DATEDIFF(Document.dt_confirm , dt_from), 0) from 
   Document where Document.id = document_id )")
  private int daysOnDtConfirm;
  ...
  public void setDtFrom(LocalDate dtFrom) {
    this.dtFrom = dtFrom;
   }

  public void setDtFrom(int daysOnDtConfirm) {
    if (this.document.getDtConfirm() != null){
        LocalDate dateTo = this.document.getDtConfirm().toLocalDate();
        this.dtFrom = dateTo.minusDays(daysOnDtConfirm);
     }
   }
    ...
}
```

Service :

```
@Service
public class DocumentServiceImpl implements DocumentService {    
  @Autowired
  DocumentRepository documentRepository;
  @Autowired
  CardRepository cardRepository;
       ...
  @Override
  @Transactional
  public void changeCard(Document document, Card card) {

     //IF ID is NULL then isNew==true!!!!
     if (card.isNew()){
            card.setDocument(document);                
            card.setDtFrom(card.getDaysOnDtConfirm());
            document.setCard(card);
            cardRepository.saveAndFlush(card);    
        }
        else{
            Card cardEdit = cardRepository.findOne(card.getId());
            if (cardEdit != null) {
                cardEdit.setDocument(document);
                cardEdit.setName(card.getName());
                cardEdit.setUnit(card.getUnit());
                cardEdit.setQuantity(card.getQuantity());
                //cardEdit.setDtFrom(card.getDtFrom());
                cardEdit.setDtFrom(card.getDaysOnDtConfirm());
                cardEdit.setDescription(card.getDescription());
                cardRepository.saveAndFlush(cardEdit);
            }

        }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public Document changeDocumentAndCards(Document document) {
        Document documentEdit = changeDocument(document);   
        List<Card> cards = document.getCards();
        //check if the same rows in DB and Client, DELETE difference
        deleteCardsFromDocument(document);
        //if not empty received from client rows  then change
        if (!cards.isEmpty()) {
            for (Card card : cards) {
                changeCard(documentEdit, card);

            }
        }

        return documentEdit;
    }
       ...
}
```

RestController:

```
    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/api/docs")
    public class DocController  {
        @Autowired
        DocumentService documentService;

        @RequestMapping(value = "",
                method = RequestMethod.GET,
                produces = {"application/json", "application/xml"})
        @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
        public @ResponseBody
        List<Document> getAllDocument(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
            List<Document> list = new ArrayList<>();
            Iterable<Document> documents = this.documentService.getDocumentAll();
            documents.forEach(list::add);
            return list;
        }
....
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}",
            method = RequestMethod.PUT,
            consumes = {"application/json", "application/xml"},
            produces = {"application/json", "application/xml"})
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public Document updateDocument(//@ApiParam(value = "The ID of the existing Document resource.", required = true)
                                   @PathVariable("id") Long id,
                                   @RequestBody Document document,
                                   HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        Document documentEdit = documentService.changeDocumentAndCards(document);
        return documentEdit;
    }
...
}
```

Comment: It would be better if you show the code for the `changeDocument()` method in `DocumentServiceImpl` class

Comment: method `changeDocument()` from  `DocumentServiceImpl`:            `@Override
    @Transactional
    public Document changeDocument(Document document) {
        Document documentEdit = documentRepository.findOne(document.getId());
documentEdit.setContragentName(document.getContragentName());
documentEdit.setDtConfirm(document.getDtConfirm());
documentEdit.setDescription(document.getDescription());
documentRepository.saveAndFlush(documentEdit);
return documentEdit;
    }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue seems to come from the `changeDocument(Document document)` method. The return value of `saveAndFlush()` call should be assigned back to `documentEdit`

**UPDATE**

The issue is that hibernate will not re-calculate the `@Formula` field after it is updated. It just fetches it from cache.

The only way I managed to get this working on my machine was to refresh the card entity after updating it. For that to work I needed to add an entity manager in the service class.

In your `DocumentServiceImpl` (actually could be any service class) class add the following:

```
public class DocumentServiceImpl implements DocumentService {

    //...

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Transactional
    public void refreshEntity(Object entity) {
        em.refresh(entity);
    }
```

Then, you should call this `refreshEntity()` method after an update, so that hibernate doesn't fetch it from cache.

This way it worked for me. Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thank you! Tried it. Responce returns the same old value for `daysOnDtConfirm`. P.S. in database the App saved new value for column `dtFrom`

Comment: Works! Thank you!

Comment: @Rudi Glad it did. Can you accept it as the right answer then?